# spring boot, jdbcTemplate, Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a query that takes one column row from database and I want to set this data to my model. My model name is Pictures and my method is follow:

```
@Override
public Pictures getPictureList() throws Exception {
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = new   JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    String sql= "select path from  bakery.pictures where id=1";
    Pictures pcList = jdbc.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Pictures>(Pictures.class));
    return pcList;
}
```

This method returns "a query was Inferred to list".
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JdbcTemplate.queryForObject()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) method to retrieve a single row by it's primary key.

```
Pictures p = jdbc.queryForObject(sql, 
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Pictures>(Pictures.class));
```

`JdbcTemplate.query()` will return multiple rows which makes little sense if you are querying by primary key.

```
List<Pictures> list = jdbc.query(sql, 
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Pictures>(Pictures.class));
Picture p = list.get(0);
```